# how to get third column value fulfilling two conditions?

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I am working on an **excel data sheet**. In that i want to get the third column value fulfilling the conditions for first two columns.My sample data plan is as below :

```
    |   A   |   B   |   C
1   |   ID1 |   ID2 |   VALUE
2   |    AA |    CC |   14
3   |    BB |    AA |   24
4   |    CC |    DD |   15
5   |    DD |    AA |   13
6   |    BB |    CC |   8
7   |    AA |    BB |   21
8   |    DD |    BB |   11
9   |    CC |    AA |   16
10  |    DD |    CC |   26
11  |    BB |    DD |   15
12  |    CC |    BB |   14
13  |    AA |    DD |   19
```

Now I want the **value** when **ID1** is say **"BB"** and **ID2** is say **"DD"** in any arbitrary cell so the value ***15*** should be displayed in that cell. and this could be used for **any value of ID1 and ID2** and the corresponding value in third column is to be be displayed.

Please help me if you know...and I prefer to use the *formulas*, not the *macro coding* although we required to use more than one formulas or complex formulas.

Comment: This can be done.  Is there a possibility that more than 1 row could satisfy your conditions?  If multiple rows can satisfy your conditions, do you want the third column results for the first row, last row, asummation of the third column?

Comment: No, there is no possibility of more than one row satisfy the conditions, all the combinations are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13="BB")*(B2:B13="DD")*(C2:C13))
```

Is a solution that will work when there is only a unique row that satisfies your condition.  Actually it will sum all results matching your conditions assuming that column C results are all numeric.

```
=INDEX(C2:C13,AGGREGATE(14,6,(A2:A13="BB")*(B2:B13="DD")*ROW(A2:A13),1)-1)
```

Will give you the last row that matches your criteria.  Will work for non numeric values in C

```
=INDEX(C2:C13,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A2:A13)/((A2:A13="BB")*(B2:B13="DD")),1)-1)
```

Will give you the first row that matches your criteria.  Will work for non numeric values in C

Comment: Thanks #Forward Ed ,
The SUMPRODUCT formula works for me.

Comment: @PavanV I edited the sumproduct formula...there was an extra -1) that should not have been there.